# Compound Assignment in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, language-lawyer, compound-assignment

I wonder if this ever was or still is a case in .Net.

> Use exp += val instead of exp = exp + val. Since exp can be
> arbitrarily complex, this can result in lots of unnecessary work. This
> forces the JIT to evaluate both copies of exp, and many times this is
> not needed. The first   statement can be optimized far better than the
> second, since the JIT can avoid evaluating the exp twice.

That's coming from an ancient article in codeproject.

And there's another one in cpp:

> However, the compound-assignment expression is not equivalent to the
> expanded version because the compound-assignment expression evaluates
> expression1 only once, while the expanded version evaluates
> expression1 twice: in the addition operation and in the assignment
> operation.

Comment: I think it may have been in reference to using `+=` on an `int` property instead of a local or field.

Comment: Do you have a link to the codeproject article or a wayback-machine copy? I’d like to know who the author was because historically there were a lot of non-experts pontificating flat-out incorrect information on CodeProject. What does the C# specification say?

Comment: @Dai, I couldn't find in c# specification

Comment: I think this needs a language tag because `+=` is an operator in both C# and VB.NET.  The [C# documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-operator#addition-assignment-operator-) says "`x += y` is equivalent to `x = x + y` except that `x` is only evaluated once", but I don't see how assigning to `x` requires evaluating it (again).  Perhaps it's only an optimization when doing something like `collection[index] += value` or `SomeObject.SomeMethod().SomeProperty += value`; otherwise, it's just shorthand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it was, and still is, a best practice in .NET. Imaging you want to add 4 to

```
myObject.MyExpensiveMethod().MyProperty
```

Obviously you wouldn't want to do:

```
myObject.MyExpensiveMethod().MyProperty = 
    myObject.MyExpensiveMethod().MyProperty + 4;
```

since it calls the expensive method twice, whereas `+=` only calls it once. You could do:

```
var temp = myObject.MyExpensiveMethod();
temp.MyProperty = temp.MyProperty + 4;
```

which is *less* expensive, but it's cheapest to do:

```
myObject.MyExpensiveMethod().MyProperty += 4;
```

Since the expensive method is only called once.

Another case is when you use a method that has side effects that you only want to call once:

```
myFactory.GetNextObject().MyProperty += 5;
```

You _certainly wouldn't do

```
myFactory.GetNextObject().MyProperty = myFactory.GetNextObject().MyProperty + 5;
```

You could again use a temp variable, but the compound assignment operator is obviously more succinct.

Granted, these are edge cases, but it's not a bad habit to get into.

Comment: @DanielB Why is `myObject.MyExpensiveMethod().MyProperty` not an expression in your sense?

Comment: @DanielB Is the article talking about a _literal_ `<Expression<T>` of some sort? It would be trivial to create an expression for `myObject.MyExpensiveMethod().MyProperty`, but the results would be the same.

Comment: @DanielB If you're talking specifically about simple `int x = 123; x += value;` scenarios, then no such requirement was included in the question.  What was included, however, is the quote "Since exp can be arbitrarily complex", and I think `myObject.MyExpensiveMethod().MyProperty` certainly qualifies as "arbitrarily complex".  You do realize that in the first text you quoted "exp" is short for "expression" and not simply, say, a local variable that happens to be named `exp`?